# How to add HTML content above the current position without a page jump

Tags: javascript, html

**TL;DR:** How can you add HTML content before the currently viewed content so that the page does not jump?

**Longer explanation**:

We have to render large manuals with sometimes hundreds of chapters in HTML. The manuals can be several MBs so loading it all at once would take to long. We can load chapters on demand.

The problem is that the HTML is responsive and the chapters have different lengths. Some have just a few sentences, some are several pages long. This means that we don't know the height of the content. The height does actually change whenever the user resizes the browser, changes the orientation or simply the font size.

The typical lazy list libraries cannot be used since they require a fixed height for each cell which is not the case here.

We would have to render a chapter outside the DOM, calculate its height and add it to the container diff.

Whenever the window size changes, all sizes would have to be recalculated.

The naive approach would be to just load a few chapters before and after the current chapter. Then poll the scroll position every second or so and check if we have to load more chapters.

The problem is that when the user scrolls up and content is added above the current position, the page jumps and the viewer gets lost.

Is there a way to deal with this problem without having to create custom scroll handlers?

Is this even a thing? Or can modern browsers easily handle 5000 page HTML documents?

Comment: You can use javascript grids : https://github.com/FancyGrid/awesome-grid

Comment: @Kiran No, the page has to stay responsive.

Comment: There is a CSSWG draft for this issue: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scroll-anchoring/

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an infinitely scrolling table, where table cells that scroll off the page are recycled and reused with different content.

Using a model-view approach (or a similar model), you can queue and dequeue reusable cells that lazy load data from your data source (e.g. in this case chapters).

The inherent benefit to doing this, is you no longer need to concern yourself with the visual adding, removing, and positioning of each chapter on the screen (and, worse, rendering them—400 chapters’ worth of text would be really choppy). Instead, you manage your data one one place, and *present* it inside the same, reused visual elements.

The tricky part is getting the table cells to work with variable heights.

[image]

Image source and some more reading: http://hrily.co/blog/2017/05/20/rendering-large-html-tables.html
Also Google around for more infinite scrolling tutorials.

Comment: The linked example uses fixed-height, while the question is about dynamic row heights. So the row height is unknown i until you actually render it, making "jump to" and scrolling upwards a difficult task

Comment: I completely realize that, but stack overflow isn’t an outsourcing firm that builds software for free. OP can now do some research on variable height infinite scrolling tables. React has one already, for example: https://github.com/coderiety/react-list

Comment: The problem is that even with variable height infinite scrolling components you have to know the height of the container before you render it.

Comment: This is a problem that has been tackled before. Not an easy one. OP will have to pre-calculate the expected height of the text given a certain font, font-size, weight, kerning, and line height. http://blog.bripkens.de/2011/06/html-javascript-calculate-text-dimensions/

Comment: that might viable on simple text in fixed-width, non-responsive. His comment says that this is not the case (responsive, "whole chapters").

Comment: Pre-rendering a page and calculating its dimensions before it’s drawn on the page? I can’t even fathom how else you could do it with today’s web stacks.

Comment: Well I guess that is the point of the question, because you can't and therefore need fancy solutions. I found tricks using `infinite scrolling` and some frameworks use dynamic resizing, but so far nothing works remotely correct when you jump to specific pages and scroll upwards.

Comment: This is why I spend my time building native apps. I’m so done with the limitations of web.